# Почему когда меняю цвет рамки QGroupBox, заголовок проваливается вниз, как исправить?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Подскажите пожалуйста вот у меня есть QGroupBox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]:

Когда я меняю цвет рамки

```
border: 2px solid #a0287f;
```

Заголовок проваливается во внутрь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно чтобы он так и оставался как на первом скриншоте, как это добиться?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox,)
import sys


class StepOne(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_name_dish = QLineEdit()
        self.line_name_dish.setPlaceholderText('Название')
        self.line_name_dish.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.line_name_dish.setTextMargins(0, 3, 5, 3)

        self.group_box_step_one = QGroupBox('Шаг первый')
        self.group_box_step_one.setStyleSheet('''QGroupBox {
                                            border: 2px solid #a0287f;
                                            font-size: 23px;
                                            font-weight: 500;
                                            color: #666666;

                }''')

        self.vbox_cook_dish = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_cook_dish.addStretch(1)
        self.vbox_cook_dish.addWidget(self.line_name_dish)
        self.vbox_cook_dish.addStretch(1)

        self.group_box_step_one.setLayout(self.vbox_cook_dish)

        self.main_box_cook_dish = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box_cook_dish.addWidget(self.group_box_step_one)
        self.setLayout(self.main_box_cook_dish)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = StepOne()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте применить данный стиль в комментарии я поместил изменения . Для более детальной настройки используйте [Таблицу стилей](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html#style-sheet-usage)

```
QGroupBox {
    border: 2px solid #a0287f;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #666666;
    margin-top: 2ex; /* начало правки */
}
QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top center;
} /* конец правки */
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает, самое обидное, что я читал таблицу стилей и пробовал так делать, но что видимо не так делал))